# PHP Redirect, Keep POSTs

Tags: php

I have an html page with a checkbox form. The form has its action pointing to a PHP script. The PHP script collects the POST variables just fine but obviously a blank screen displays because it goes to *www.example/script.php* once executed.

How I do get PHP to go to another URL for more form submission information while keeping those POSTs intact?

`header()` and metaredirect seem to overrule everything and not collect the data... How do I collect that data into POSTs and then automatically go to another html page for another form with a PHP script attached as its action?

Thanks and sorry if I worded this in a confusing manner.

Comment: Put the `POST` data in a session variable.

Comment: I'll just write `echo "<form method='POST' action='...' ...>...</form>"`, but I'm curious if there's a better way to do.

Answer (score 5):

You could either store the `$_POST` variables in `$_SESSION` and then submit them when the final part of the form is completed, or you could have the intermediary page store these values as hidden inputs and submit them to the final page.

Comment: I see what you are saying and I can try doing the session... but how do I get to another page once that script.php executes? It just displays a blank page... how do I get it to shoot to another html page so the user can fill out more forms? Thanks!

Comment: Why not display the next part of the form right there on that page? If you really want to redirect the user, issue a `header('Location: www.mysite.com/nextpage.php');`

Comment: could I make the "next" submit button link to the next form page and somehow have all of the form information be put into POSTs? Would that require me to use the php on the same html page or could I still have it in its own file?

Comment: also, I am willing to poke around in DHTML and ajax to achieve this.. also, frames

Answer (score 2):

I've found that this code works almost all the time (except in some cases where you want to forward using custom post data and the client doesn't support javascript).

This is done by abusing the `307 Temporary Redirect` which seems to forward `POST` data, or by creating a self submitting javascript form.

**This is a hack though, only use it if you MUST forward the POST data.**

```
<?php

function redirectNowWithPost( $url, array $post_array = NULL )
{
    if( is_null( $post_array ) ) { //we want to forward our $_POST fields
        header( "Location: $url", TRUE, 307 );
    } elseif( ! $post_array ) { //we don't have any fields to forward
        header( "Location: $url", TRUE );
    } else { //we have some to forward let's fake a custom post w/ javascript
        ?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $url ); ?>" method="post">
<script type="text/javascript">
//this is a hack so that the submit function doesn't get overridden by a field called "submit"
document.forms[0].___submit___ = document.forms[0].submit;
</script>
<?php print createHiddenFields( $post_array ); ?>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms[0].___submit___();
</script>
        <?php
    }
    exit();
}

function createHiddenFields( $value, $name = NULL )
{
    $output = "";
    if( is_array( $value ) ) {
        foreach( $value as $key => $value ) {
            $output .= createHiddenFields( $value, is_null( $name ) ? $key : $name."[$key]" );
        }
    } else {
        $output .= sprintf("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" />",
            htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $name ) ),
            htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $value ) )
        );
    }
    return $output;
}
```